# Problems of installing npm nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-install, nodemon

I encountered some problems while trying to install nodemon with the command line of `'npm install -g nodemon'` as shown in the image below.

[image: Console output]

Comment: Right click ====> open as Administrator

Comment: Its says it in the log. You do not have access to `/usr`. On Linux try: `sudo npm i -g nodemon`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never need to run `npm install -g` with root privileges - if you are getting permission errors then this means that npm has been installed incorrectly.  The npm website provides fairly comprehensive documentation on how to fix this - https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

The best options are to either use a package manager to install npm, such as Homebrew on MacOS.  Node Version Manager (NVM) can also ease the process, as well as providing support for using different node versions.  Alternatively you can either change the ownership of `/usr/local` so that your current user has permissions there, or change the folder used by npm to one owner by the current user.

Comment: Most linux package managers will install node this way. Since -g is a system-wide change, then running it with root is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: This is the permanent solution that would help instead of adding sudo every time. Sometimes even sudo doesn't work if node is downloaded incorrectly. Another link, https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update, shows how to install NVM and remove the currently installed version of node and re-download it with nvm to fix this issue permanently.

Answer (score 2):

As the error suggests you need to run npm install -g with root privileges.

either open an Administration console in Windows, or use sudo in Linux:

```
sudo npm install -g nodemon
```

If you want to avoid that, you can look into using [NVM](https://github.com/creationix/nvm), which can provide a global node_modules that does not depend on root privileges.

Answer (score 0):

write on your terminal or cmd :

sudo chown -R $(whoami) $(npm config get prefix)/{lib/node_modules,bin,share}

enter your password of PC :
then try

npm install -g nodemon

*****Hope the problem is solved*****[See the solution in screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDAnp.png) .